# Multilingual dates in gridview

Tags: .net, asp.net

I'm replacing a website that was previously HTML only.

I put a GridView on the French and the English page and I'm getting 2 fields: A date and a currency.

For the date, I need to transform it into a long date format. The English part isn't very hard, but when I get to the French page, I can't transform it into a long date format with French words (i.e.:Mardi instead of Tuesday).

Is there any way to format the string with French date words instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `Thread.CurrentCulture` to a French culture (fr-FR), the day and month names will be in French.  But you will also get French numeric formats (comma as decimal separator etc).

If this is not what you want, you could consider creating a custom culture, based in fr-FR but with English numeric format.

Alternatively you can explicitly convert it the DateTime to a string using the French culture, e.g.:

```
private static CultureInfo FrenchCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
...
string frenchDate = myDate.ToString("D", FrenchCulture);
...
```

Comment: Slight modification since I was using two different pages: 
<%@ Page Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="name.aspx.vb" Inherits="Name._Default" Culture="fr-FR" %>

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking the DateTime object converting its value, check out the options with ToString and the current culture: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx